# Tabs in Properties sidebar of the 3D view?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I can add tabs in the Properties sidebar of the Dopesheet Editor, or the NLA Editor. But i cannot add tabs in the Properties sidebar of the 3D view.

But the UI guidelines says this should be possible by simply adding a bl category to the panel header. bl_category = "Category Name"

See here: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Projects/UI/Tab_Guidelines

What makes the Properties sidebar of the 3D view so special? What would i need to do to allow tabs there too?

Comment: From the link _"Tabs are added to applicable toolbars and property regions"_ AFAIK in 3d view can have tabs in `bl_region_type`  'TOOLS' but not in 'UI' (properties sidebar)  Not sure how you determine if a particular region has / can have tabs.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that i have to grep through the C code then.